# How do I Dedupe the following array using a hash table

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, hashtable

The array

```
const users = dedup([
{ id: 1, email: 'foo@example.com' },
{ id: 2, email: 'sho@example.com' },
{ id: 1, email: 'bin@example.com' },
]); 
/* would ideally like it to  return 
 Object {
 email: "foo@example.com",
 email: "bin@example.com",
 id:1
},  Object {
 email: "sho@example.com",
 id:2
 } */
```

The Hash Table

```
function dedup(arr) {
var hashTable = {};

return arr.filter(function (el) {
    var key = JSON.stringify(el);
    var match = Boolean(hashTable[key]);
    return (match ? false : hashTable[key] = true);
});
 }
```

My returns statement that only filters out exact duplicates and doesn't join similar id's with different email addresses

```
console.log(users); 
/* currently returns 
Object {
email: "foo@example.com",
id:1
},  Object {
email: "sho@example.com",
id:2
 },
 { id: 1, email: 'bin@example.com' },
]); */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function dedup(arr) {
  var hashTable = {};

  arr.forEach(function(el) {
    if (!hashTable.hasOwnProperty(el.id)) {
        hashTable[el.id] = [];
    }
    hashTable[el.id].push(el.email);
  });

  return hashTable;
}
```

Result should be:

```
{
  1: ['bin@example.com', 'foo@example.com' ],
  2: ['sho@example.com']
}
```

Hope this helped.